# Dropdown menu with equal width for justified button group in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Using bootstrap, I'm trying to make a dropdown menu inside one of the buttons in a justified button group. More specifically, I want the dropdown menu list elements to have the same width as the dropdown toggle button. The code below does everything except the width of the dropdown elements is different from the toggle button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <style>
   .pull-right{
        margin-top: 7px
    } 
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Justified Button Groups</h2>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</a>
    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sony<span class="caret pull-right"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should consider using a structure closer to the docs for [button groups](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-button-elements) by wrapping your first two buttons with a `btn-group` div and by removing the `.btn` classes from your dropdown list.

For the width, use `min-width: 100%` to override the default `min-width: 160px;`.

Working Example:

```css
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-wide {
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <h2>Justified Button Groups</h2>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Apple</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Samsung</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sony <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-wide">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage with give width to drop down menu

```
.dropdown-menu{ width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since bootstrap 5 just add the class w-100 to the dropdown-menu element to achive this according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 0):

try this code :)

```
.dropdown-menu{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```